# variable generation referencing different rows

Tags: r

I'm at a loss to cycle through a data frame and calculate a variable that is a function of different/multiple rows.  Please see the following data as an example.

```html
date var1 var2 var3
12/29/2013 10 34 0
12/30/2013 10 34 15
12/31/2013 8 27 15
1/1/2014 8 27 0
1/2/2014 2 7 10
1/3/2014 10 35 20
1/4/2014 13 45 10
```

I would like to create a variable that is a function of the current row and the next row.  For example,

var4(12/31/2013) = var1(12/31/2013) + var2(1/1/2014) + var3(12/31/2013)

For the last element in the dataframe, there is no (n+1) variable, so I'd like to assign a missing value/exception value in that case.  Any guidance you could provide would be wonderful.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: just shift the vector `var2` one element back: `your.dataframe$var4 <- with(your.dataframe, var1 + var3 + c(var2[-1],NA))`

Comment: @MaratTalipov - that's a really good answer.  You should post it

Answer (score 3):

you could try

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>%
     mutate(var4=var1+lead(var2)+var3)
```

Comment: Very nice.  I didn't know about `lead()`